# How to run HAXM on Mac OSX Hight Sierra

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I have just updated my OSX to High Sierra. Since then My android Emulators don't run! I have deleted all the old emulators and created a new one. But it is too slow. It seems HAXM is disabled right now!

How can I enable and run HAXM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAXM is supported until mac OS 10.12. They have not support for mac OSX 10.13 yet.

> Supported Operating Systems:
>
> Mac* OS X* 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to macOS* 10.12 (Sierra)

[check here for more](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

> 1- Go to Recovery Mode by restarting and holding down ⌘+R until Apple  logo appears.
>
> 2- In the top menu click Utilities > Terminal.
>
> 3- In the Terminal window type and press Enter:

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

> Then you can install HAXM from:
>   Download the driver from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/) and unzip it.
>
> Open a terminal and go to the directory of the driver :
>       cd Downloads/haxm-macosx_v6_2_0
>       # edit the file and look for 10.12
>   Add 10.13 after 10.12, and save the file
>   Run it :
>   Make sure it works :

```
sudo kextload -bundle-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

See this post
[here](https://blog.celogeek.com/201708/672/android-studio-emulator-haxm-on-mac-os-high-serria-10-13/)